# How can define "materializecss" modal "before" (beforeload) functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, material-design

I have used [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) framework but stuck in modal functionality.

I have made popup modal for image with following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="media-insert"> <a href="#img2" class="modal-trigger"><img src="images/slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive" /></a>
  <div class="modal" id="img2">
    <div class="modal-content"> <img src="images/slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive" /> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="modal-action modal-close"><span class="mdi-navigation-close"></span></a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
```

CSS:

```
.media-insert .modal {
    width: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

But the issue is that,  image and modal (wrapper) both are not aligned in `center`. And modal wrapper is also not responsive as like [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) popup

I have tried this code for callback:

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    ready: function () {
        var modelImgW = $('.modal-content img').innerWidth();
        var modelImgH = $('.modal-content img').innerHeight();
        $('.media-insert .model').css({
            'height': modelImgH + 'px'
        });
        $('.media-insert .model').css({
            'width': modelImgW + 'px'
        });

    }
});
```

not getting, Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about my earlier answer, I thought you were not getting the modal to work at all...

You used some CSS rules that affect the responsiveness and width of the modal, and for center aligning the content in the modal you just need another rule. Just modified the CSS, replaced the images and added the `btn` class - you can run the snippet and click "Full page" to see it working.

```js
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
```

```css
.media-insert .modal {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.media-insert .modal .modal-content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="media-insert">
  <a href="#img2" class="btn modal-trigger">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc768be1b3c" class="img-responsive" />
  </a>
  <div class="modal" id="img2">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc768be1b3c" class="img-responsive" /> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="modal-action modal-close"><span class="mdi-navigation-close"></span></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Their documentation of button-triggered modals](http://materializecss.com/modals.html#button-trigger) may help you further.